# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Python 3 and Python 2.7 compatibility

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to compare two lists of strings:

```
text_line = [u'\u2502 id               \u2502 na \u2502 email   \u2502', u'\u2502                  \u2502 me \u2502         \u2502']  
print( text_line == [
             "│ id               │ na │ email   │",
             "│                  │ me │         │",
])
```

It gives the warning: *UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode* and prints *False*.

If I add **.decode('utf-8')** at the end of each string in the list it works fine in Python 2.7 and prints *True*:

```
print( text_line == [
       "│ id               │ na │ email   │".decode('utf-8'),
       "│                  │ me │         │".decode('utf-8'),
])
```

**But it does not work in Python 3.X giving the following error:**

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Is there a way that would work for both Python 2.7 and Python 3.X?

Comment: In this case, use the `u` for a unicode literal, which doens't do anything in Python 3. But in general, Python 2 and Python 3 are incompatible. Indeed, the primary reason that backwards-compatibility was broken was *how unicode/strings are handled*. Python 2 is long past its end of life, why do you need to support it?

Comment: Or, to make this easier in general,  use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, but it really behooves you to grok the difference between a unicode strings and byte strings, and they way they are handled differently between Python 2 and 3, or else you will keep bumping into these problems trying to make your code 2/3 compatible (which again, is really something that should be avoided at all costs at this point).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much, it works! RHEL 7 still depends on Python 2, that's why I need to support it.

Comment: I don't understand. Why does the fact that RHEL 7 depends on Python 2 mean you have to use Python 2?

Comment: RHEL/CentOS 7 has a python3 package: `yum install python3`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I work on the project that will be used by users who are on RHEL 7, and since RHEL 7 depends on Pyhton 2, then my project should be Python 2 compatible so that they could run it. That's what I understood from my mentor's explanation, I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: @anechkayf If you may add a dependency to the project, have a look at [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/), a 2/3 compatibility library providing you with functions and proxies to abstract away from the version differences.